Git Extension Api log function with author not working as expected
I am writing a vscode extension and I am using the git extension api to get the commits done by a user, I am using the log function on the repository interface, the log function takes an option property which is constructed using another interface, logOptions, which has an author property, and the returned commits from the log function is an empty array and it should not be.
I have tried passing different values for the author property. I have tried using the username specified in the git config, that returned an empty array, I tried the email in the config, that also returned an empty array. I have tried username <email> , this is the format when running git log in the terminal of the repository and that also returned an empty array. I passed an empty string and that returned all commits done by all users.
see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
